# How to load everything from one folder?

Tags: javascript, directory

Let's say I have folder `scripts` with 10 javascript files and instead of doing this:

```
<script src="scripts/js1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/js2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/js3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/js4.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/js5.js"></script>
//and so on...
```

I want to do this:

```
<script src="scripts/*"></script>
```

which load ALL files in `scripts`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think your first hurdle would be that if you are looking for a client-side only solution, that the script running on the client has no idea what files are in the folder on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Won't be as easy as that, here is what you are looking for:

[How can I include all JavaScript files in a directory via JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175008/how-can-i-include-all-javascript-files-in-a-directory-via-javascript-file)

Answer (score -1):

What you try to achieve is cumbersome from the client side. You can achieve the same through server-side scripting before you load your html file. You can use a task runner tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) etc. (or write a script) that will traverse your target directory, retrieve all the *.js file paths and append their script tags in your html file.

Another solution is to use a tool to concatenate all your js files in one bundle file and only load that file from your html file. There are plenty of tools out there to do that