# How to include all .js file from a folder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any function to include all JavaScript files from a folder using JavaScript. Since I'm have plenty if `.js` file to include.

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can load the modules using [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) or [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include all JavaScript files in a directory via JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175008/how-can-i-include-all-javascript-files-in-a-directory-via-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really brief way to require all files (node.js-style):

```
var fs = require('fs');

// assuming all things are files
fs.readdirSync('path/to/dir').forEach(function(elementName) {
    require('path/to/dir' + elementName);
});
```

Generally though people will make an index file in the root of the folder that individually requires each file and exports the appropriate fields.

Comment: he can do it with any lang. that have access to the file-system, that wasn't the question though... by the question and tags seems like he is looking for a way to access it from the client

Comment: I wasn't totally sure, even though he mentioned angular. Thought I'd throw this out there in case it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't, as JS cannot read the file system. You could:

- Create an array of filenames
- Create a php (or other server-side) script that returns the file list and fetch the list with ajax

Once you have the list of files, you can load them with JS:

```
var js=document.createElement("script");
js.src=url;
document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Comment: It's an angularJs question, your answer is irrelevant