# Listing script and link tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In angularjs we create script files to components, directives, services and so on, in addition to a list of css files, and at the end we have hundreds of script and link tags to add to the index.html page.

Is there an alternative such as specifying

```
<script src="scripts/*"></script>
<link href="styles/*" rel="stylesheet">
```

to get all the script files in the directory **scripts** and the css files in the **styles** directory?

If not, what is the best practice? (At the development level not the build level)

Comment: You can use [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) for this

Comment: It'd be useful if you called out your current dev/build environment -- e.g., are you using Gulp, Grunt, or similar; how are you currently expressing dependencies, etc. RequireJS, for instance, solves this by dynamically loading dependencies in dev (you don't list them in the HTML) and building a bundle for release.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175008/how-can-i-include-all-javascript-files-in-a-directory-via-javascript-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Gulp Concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to generate a single file from your scripts. From here, you can easily minify your scripts when going into production